# Core Java - To implement Fish in an Aquarium

Tags: java, multithreading

**Problem Statement:**

1. A fish has to move in a 2D Aquarium.
2. At no point two fishes can be at the same Location.

**Challenges:**

1. To generate a random direction in which every fish will move.
2. Fish should not go beyond the Aquarium specifications.
3. Maintaining a collection which contains the locations of all fishes in the aquarium.

**Approach:**

1. I used multi threading via Java so that all the fishes can move at the same time.
2. Used Enum's to extract direction for X & Y co-ordinates randomly.
3. Created a Fish Class which extends Location Class.

Please suggest if there could have been a different approach used for this question since I am an Intermediate Level Java Programmer.

### Location Class

```
public class Location {

    public int x;

    public int y;


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
            Location other = (Location) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    public Location(int Size) {
        setRandomLocation(Size);
        synchronized (Aquarium.location_list) {
            Aquarium.location_list.add(this);
        }
    }
    public Location() {

    }
    public void setRandomLocation(int Size){

        int location_exist_ind=0 ;

        while(location_exist_ind==0){               

            this.x = (int)(Math.random() * Size);               

            this.y = (int)(Math.random() * Size);       

            location_exist_ind=checkLocation(this); 
        }       
    }   
    public int checkLocation(Location obj){ 
        int temp_ind=0;
        synchronized (Aquarium.location_list) {

            if(Aquarium.location_list.size()!=0)
            for(Location loc1 : Aquarium.location_list )
            {
                if(obj.equals(loc1)){
                    System.out.println("This location" + obj.x  
                    + " , "
                    +obj.y+ " is already taken by another fish , so generating the random location again.");
                    temp_ind=0;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;          
                }  
                else temp_ind=1;    
            }
            else temp_ind=1;
        }
        return temp_ind;
    }

    public void setNextLocation(int x,int y){

        int X_location = 0;
        int Y_location = 0;

        int location_exist_ind=0 ;

        while(location_exist_ind==0){               

            X_location= Direction_X.getRandom_direction_X(x);

            Y_location= Direction_Y.getRandom_direction_Y(y);

            Location temp_loc= new Location();

            temp_loc.setX(X_location);      

            temp_loc.setY(Y_location);

            location_exist_ind=checkLocation(temp_loc);

        }
        this.setX(X_location);
        this.setY(Y_location);

    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

### Aquarium class

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Aquarium {

    static int size= 0;
    static int number_of_fishes = 1000;
    static int number_of_moves = 0;

    static LinkedList<Location> location_list = new LinkedList<Location>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scn= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the size of the aquarium :");

        size=scn.nextInt();

        while(number_of_fishes >= Math.pow(size,2)){
            System.out.println("Please enter the correct number of fishes in the aquarium , MAx allowed fishes are 2 to the power size of Aquarium: ");
            number_of_fishes=scn.nextInt(); 
        }

        System.out.println("Please enter the Number of Minimum Moves for each of the fishes :");

        number_of_moves=scn.nextInt();

        Fish[] fishes = new Fish[number_of_fishes];

        Thread[] thr = new Thread[number_of_fishes];

        for (int i=0;i<number_of_fishes;i++){

            fishes[i]= new Fish(size, number_of_moves ,i);

            thr[i]= new Thread(fishes[i]);

            thr[i].start();
        }

        try {
            for (int i=0;i<number_of_fishes;i++)
            thr[i].join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Final Location list goes like : ");

        for(Location loc : location_list){
            System.out.println(loc.x + " , " + loc.y);
        }
    }

}
```

### Fish class

```
public class Fish extends Location implements Runnable{

    int moves=0;
    int fishnum=0;
    public Fish(int AquariumSize, int moves , int fishnum) {
        super(AquariumSize);
        this.moves=moves;
        this.fishnum=fishnum;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i< moves;i++){
            if(i==0)
            System.out.println(" Initial location of Fish " + fishnum + " Location is "+this.x + " , "+ this.y);

            this.setNextLocation(x, y);

            System.out.println(" Location of Fish " + fishnum + " Move number is "+ i + " , new location is "+this.x + " , " + this.y);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Direction enumeration

```
public enum Direction_X {


    RIGHT(1),
    NONE(0),
    LEFT(-1);

    public int direction_X_ind;

    Direction_X(int X)
    {
        direction_X_ind = X;
    }

    public static int getRandom_direction_X(int x)
    {
        int X=x;

        if(X!=0 && X!=Aquarium.size-1)
        {
            X = X + values()[(int) (Math.random() * (values().length))].direction_X_ind;

        }
        else if(x>=Aquarium.size-1)
        {
            X = X + values()[ (int) (Math.random() * (values().length-1)) + 1 ].direction_X_ind;
        }
        else
        {
            X = X + values()[(int) (Math.random() * (values().length-1))].direction_X_ind;
        }
        return (X);
    }
}

public enum Direction_Y {

    UP(1),
    NONE(0),
    DOWN(-1);

    public int direction_Y_ind;

    Direction_Y(int Y)
    {
        direction_Y_ind = Y;
    }

    public static int getRandom_direction_Y(int Y)
    {
        if(Y!=0 && Y != Aquarium.size-1)
        {
            Y = Y + values()[ (int) (Math.random() * (values().length))].direction_Y_ind;       
        }
        else if(Y >= Aquarium.size-1)
        {
            Y = Y + values()[ (int) (Math.random() * (values().length-1)) + 1 ].direction_Y_ind;
        }
        else
        {
            Y = Y + values()[ (int) (Math.random() * (values().length-1))].direction_Y_ind;
        }
        return (Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be a good example for a code review. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi Pascal, thanks for the comment , I'll perform the code review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi threading will only make your logic harder. The fishes' direction of movement is dependent on other fishes so this makes no sense letting each and every one of them move on its own with synchronization. Perhaps a better approach will be something involving a game loop. You can read more about it [here](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html). Basically its a more sophisticated implementation of an event loop.

Comment: Hi Muli, Initially when I implemented this program it was made with the same looping logic you've mentioned but then somehow I felt Multi-Threading approach would be better because Looping approach will give the highest priority to the the first fish in the loop but in practical life all the fishes should be swimming in parallel if they've got ample space to do so.

Comment: You could shuffle the collection containing the fishes :)

Comment: Agreed we can shuffle the collection to achieve it as well.

Comment: But the only problem with that is we are deviating from the problem statement and we are ensuring only one fish will swim at a time which should not be the case , isn't it ? :)

Comment: Not really, they all move at the same frame (when you call `render()`) so they all appear to move at the same time. If you're implying that threads run in parallel you are wrong (unless they run on a different core)

Comment: @JayeshMulwani When you run your application with a single cpu,  they dont run simultaenously either.

Comment: @Jayesh Making mistakes is the best kind of learning experience one can have, so I'd encourage you to continue with your threaded approach until you see why game designs generally have a loop that enables you to really synchronize actions. Reminds me of the first time I wrote a pacman game and made the same mistake.